# Meaning of star in a OSM tag

Tags: tags, openstreetmap

I am new to working with OSM and have a very basic question. What does the value '*' mean for a tag? For example width=*, highway=*. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` is a wildcard for any tag value. For example, when a way has a `highway=*` tag, its value could be `primary`, `secondary`, `tertiary`, `residential`, or one of many other possible values.